# IdHTTPServer and IdHTTP with Encoding UTF8

Tags: delphi, utf-8, indy, delphi-xe7, indy10

I am testing a localhost server using `TIdHTTPServer` and `TIdHTTP`. I am having problems with encoding UTF8 data.

client side:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  res: string;
begin
  res:=IdHTTP1.Get('http://localhost/?msg=đi chơi thôi');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(res);
end;
```

Server side:

```
procedure TForm1.OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ARequestInfo.Params.Values['msg']); // ?i ch?i th?i

  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'chào các bạn'; // chào các b?n
end;
```

I want to send `đi chơi thôi` and receive `chào các bạn`.  But the server receives `?i ch?i th?i` and the client receives `chào các b?n`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` transmits the URL exactly as you give it, but `http://localhost/?msg=đi chơi thôi` is not a valid URL that can be transmitted as-is, as URLs can only contain ASCII characters.  Unreserved ASCII characters can be used as-is, but reserved and non-ASCII characters MUST be charset-encoded into bytes and then those bytes must be url-encoded in `%HH` format, eg:

```
IdHTTP1.Get('http://localhost/?msg=%C4%91i%20ch%C6%A1i%20th%C3%B4i');
```

You must ensure you pass only valid url-encoded URLs to `TIdHTTP`.

In this example, the URL is hard-coded, but if you need something more dynamic then use the `TIdURI` class, eg:

```
IdHTTP1.Get('http://localhost/?msg=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode('đi chơi thôi'));
```

`TIdHTTPServer` will then decode the parameter data as you are expecting.  Both `TIdURI` and `TIdHTTPServer` use UTF-8 by default.

When sending a response, you are only setting a `CharSet`, but you are not setting a `ContentType`.  So `TIdHTTPServer` will set the `ContentType` to `'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'`, overwriting your `CharSet`.  You need to explicitly set the `ContentType` yourself so you can specify a custom `CharSet`, eg:

```
AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain';
AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'chào các bạn';
```

Or:

```
AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'chào các bạn';
```

---

On a side note, `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  The `OnCommand...` events are fired in the context of a worker thread, not the main UI thread.  So accessing `Memo1` directly like you are is not thread-safe. You MUST synchronize with the main UI thread in order to access UI controls safely, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.OnCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  msg: string;
begin
  msg := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['msg'];
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(msg);
    end
  );
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Hello Remy,  today I was investigating a similar issue of a 3rd party lib which uses Indy internally... I think the solution you posted here (provide values for `CharSet ` and `ContentType`) should also be applied to TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoExecute in the exception handling, because in case the exception message is in far-eastern language (non-ASCII), the response text will be messed up also.

Comment: @EdwinYip thanks, I will look into it when I have some free time. In the meantime, I have [opened a ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/249) for it

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand how to get a proper Unicode parameter value in a POST request if the request was sent as UTF-8.

Comment: @Paul what don't you understand? I thought I was very clear on what is needed. What is the actual problem you are having? Perhaps post a new question about it